# Stress vector that acts on the plane

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics

[image]

A flat plate with dimensions 110x220 mm is subject to the indicated stresses.
Assume that $\sigma_{zz} = 120\ MPa$.
Determine the stress vector that acts on the plane defined by the z axis and the dashed line segment.

In the solution it is written that

$$\theta = 90^o - \arctan\left(\frac{0.11}{0.22}\right)$$

$$n(\theta= 63.43^o) = [\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0 ] = [0.44730,   0.89440,   0]$$

I thought that θ=0 and therefore n=[0 0 1] since so n is perpendicular to the plane.

Why I am wrong?
Could someone explain me?

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{n}$ is the normal of the plane which is defined by z (red) , and the dashed line (green).

[image]

The direction of the green line can be obtained by the diagonal (apologies for the bad drawing). $\theta$ is denoted with blue.

From the right angle you can see that:

$$\tan\theta = \frac{110}{220} \Rightarrow$$
$$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{110}{220}\right) $$
Essentially it has the same direction as y' in the figure you are showing.

However, I would have expected the vector to be

$$\vec{n}= [-\sin\theta, \cos\theta, 0]$$

Are you sure, you've written the correct formula?

Comment: Hi, see if my updated answer makes it any clearer?

Comment: Because it says in the exersice **Determine the stress vector that acts on the plane defined by the z axis and the dashed line segment.**

Comment: Before answering, there is a difference between your $\vec{n}$ and my $\vec{n}$. Are you sure you copied your's correctly from the solution.

Comment: Break down the y' in $\vec{\epsilon}_x$ and  $\vec{\epsilon}_y$.